# How To Present A NavigationController With the Second Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to present a `UINavigationController` modally however, I want to present the second controller within that stack rather than the root. How can this be done?

Comment: What does it mean "within that stack rather than the root"?

Comment: I have a Navigation Controller which can push to a second, third controller and so on. So 'root' controller, second, third etc. I want to present modally a navigationController however, I want the controller to be the second controller on the navigation controller 'stack'. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You have presented modaly navigation controller, but the second controller is got pushed in the navigation controller at the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationController` provides a method `setViewControllers(_:animated:)` and with its help you can configure the navigation stack the way you want.

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
navigationController.setViewControllers([rootViewController, secondViewController], animated: false)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
```